# Update list items in PagingLibrary w/o using Room (Network only)

Tags: android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-paging, android-architecture-paging

I'm using **Paging Library** to load data from network using `ItemKeyedDataSource`. After fetching items user can edit them, this updates are done inside in **Memory** cache (no database like Room is used).

Now since the `PagedList` itself cannot be updated (discussed [here](https://plus.google.com/communities/105153134372062985968/posts/108743107196401803953)) I have to recreate `PagedList` and pass it to the `PagedListAdapter`.

The update itself is no problem but after updating the `recyclerView` with the new `PagedList`, the list jumps to the beginning of the list destroying **previous** scroll position. Is there anyway to update PagedList while keeping scroll position (like how it works with **Room**)?

**DataSource** is implemented this way:

```
public class MentionKeyedDataSource extends ItemKeyedDataSource<Long, Mention> {

    private Repository repository;
    ...
    private List<Mention> cachedItems;

    public MentionKeyedDataSource(Repository repository, ..., List<Mention> cachedItems){
        super();

        this.repository = repository;
        this.teamId = teamId;
        this.inboxId = inboxId;
        this.filter = filter;
        this.cachedItems = new ArrayList<>(cachedItems);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Long> params, final @NonNull ItemKeyedDataSource.LoadInitialCallback<Mention> callback) {
        Observable.just(cachedItems)
                .filter(() -> return cachedItems != null && !cachedItems.isEmpty())
                .switchIfEmpty(repository.getItems(..., params.requestedLoadSize).map(...))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(response -> callback.onResult(response.data.list));
    }

    @Override
    public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<Long> params, final @NonNull ItemKeyedDataSource.LoadCallback<Mention> callback) {
        repository.getOlderItems(..., params.key, params.requestedLoadSize)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(response -> callback.onResult(response.data.list));
    }

    @Override
    public void loadBefore(@NonNull LoadParams<Long> params, final @NonNull ItemKeyedDataSource.LoadCallback<Mention> callback) {
        repository.getNewerItems(..., params.key, params.requestedLoadSize)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(response -> callback.onResult(response.data.list));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Long getKey(@NonNull Mention item) {
        return item.id;
    }
}
```

The **PagedList** created like this:

```
PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(preFetchedItems != null && !preFetchedItems.isEmpty()
                ? preFetchedItems.size()
                : PAGE_SIZE * 2
        ).build();

pagedMentionsList = new PagedList.Builder<>(new MentionKeyedDataSource(mRepository, team.id, inbox.id, mCurrentFilter, preFetchedItems)
        , config)
        .setFetchExecutor(ApplicationThreadPool.getBackgroundThreadExecutor())
        .setNotifyExecutor(ApplicationThreadPool.getUIThreadExecutor())
        .build();
```

The **PagedListAdapter** is created like this:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<Item, ItemAdapter.ItemHolder> { //Adapter from google guide, Nothing special here.. }

mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Mention>() {
            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(Item oldItem, Item newItem) {
                return oldItem.id == newItem.id;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(Item oldItem, Item newItem) {
                return oldItem.equals(newItem);
            }
        });
```

, and updated like this:

```
mAdapter.submitList(pagedList);
```

P.S: If there is a better way to update list items without using Room please share.

Comment: Are you able to implement the below solution? Is it working ? can you please update with sample code for reference.

Comment: Have you implemented this, share it here if you got a solution

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is to invalidate current `DataSource` each time you update your data.

What I would do:

- move networking logic from `MentionKeyedDataSource` to new class that extends `PagedList.BoundaryCallback` and set it when building your `PagedList`.
- move all you data to some `DataProvider` that holds all your downloaded data and has reference to `DataSource`. Each time data is updated in `DataProvider` invalidate current `DataSource`

Something like that maybe

```
    val dataProvider = PagedDataProvider()
    val dataSourceFactory = InMemoryDataSourceFactory(dataProvider = dataProvider)
```

where

```
class PagedDataProvider : DataProvider<Int, DataRow> {

    private val dataCache = mutableMapOf<Int, List<DataRow>>()
    override val sourceLiveData = MutableLiveData<DataSource<Int, DataRow>>()

    //implement data add/remove/update here
    //and after each modification call
    //sourceLiveData.value?.invalidate()
}
```

and

```
class InMemoryDataSourceFactory<Key, Value>(
    private val dataProvider: DataProvider<Key, Value>
) : DataSource.Factory<Key, Value>() {

    override fun create(): DataSource<Key, Value> {
        val source = InMemoryDataSource(dataProvider = dataProvider)
        dataProvider.sourceLiveData.postValue(source)
        return source
    }
}
```

This approach is very similar to what `Room` does - every time table row is updated - current `DataSource` is invalidated and `DataSourceFactory` creates new data source.

Comment: Do you have any samples for the above-suggested solution for reference? I was looking for a solution to the same problem and found this one. The above solution makes sense. What is a DataProvider class in the sample code? What is the purpose of it?  Is it a custom class? InMemoryDataSource will extend any of the data sources - PageKeyedDataSource, ItemKeyedDataSource, PositionalDataSource. Is that understanding correct? It will be great if you can write some blogs with a detailed solution. I couldn't find any online other than this, which give some reference to the solution.

Comment: I experimented this approach to see how to design my data layer, there are couple of issues come across, eg. Observability, Propagating error, Invalidating data.
I realized that implementing all these on my own leads to reinventing the wheel, so I'd prefer to use Room instead

Answer (score 0):

You can modify directly in your adapter if you called `currentList` like that

```
class ItemsAdapter(): PagedListAdapter<Item, ItemsAdapter.ViewHolder(ITEMS_COMPARATOR) {
    ...
    fun changeItem(position: Int,newData:String) {
        currentList?.get(position)?.data = newData
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }
   
}
```